# Trigger to add a row to a table when it is created

Tags: sqlite

I have an `sqlite` table to store all the topics that exist in my forum. My idea would be, since I have a global topic, to insert a row as I create the table that has the information on the global topic.

Such as:

```
CREATE TABLE ForumTopic(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   CONTENT        CHAR(250),
);

Create trigger "WHEN I CREATE TABLE ForumTopic":
     "automatically add a row that creates the general topic".
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A table is created exactly once. Executing an INSERT would not be any more effort than creating a trigger.

Comment: sqlite seems not to support trigger for create table [https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Comment: My idea would be to create the row as the table was created since the admin of the server might forget to add it from the start which would create issues related to user permission to view that topic in the forum. I have managed to find a sneaky solution to add permission to all the users from the start even if the topic does not exist. Thank you both.